# SQLException java.sql.SQLException: Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

My `user` table has previously string primary key now i added a new field `userid bigint(20)` and made this primary key.
then added

```
ALTER TABLE smsusers AUTO_INCREMENT = 2335;
```

Total records in user table are  2334 next record should take value 2335
and should be auto incremented as records are added.

Problem is while inserting data from my application it is showing
following error

```
SQLException  java.sql.SQLException: Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value
```

How to resolve this problem

**EDIT:** while trying to insert new data

```
    INSERT INTO `dbname`.`smsusers` ( `password`, `fname`, `lname`,
 `mailid`, `dob`, `gender`) VALUES ('asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf',
 'asdf@asdf.com', '2013-10-10', 'm');
```

It is showing following error

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 1
```

EDIT: 
Initially my primary key was id than i added userid and made this primary key

MY table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `smsusers` (
 `id` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `lname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mailid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `dob` date NOT NULL,
 `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
 `userid` int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
 KEY `id_pk_unique` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

While inserting data in smsusers it it only taking default value at 0 not the incremented value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run below queries. Then no worries. :)

```
   ALTER TABLE smsusers MODIFY COLUMN userid INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT;

   ALTER TABLE smsusers AUTO_INCREMENT = 2335;
```

Comment: This problem was from last 2 months. New users were not able to register on my site. After analyzing I find above problem.                 Thanks for resolving my problem.

Comment: I have no idea what this did, but it solved my same issue

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you are not using setter for your primary key in model class.

```
@Entity
public class BlogDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="B_Id",nullable=false)
private int b_Id;
@Column(name="EmailId")
private String emailId;
@Column(name="Title")
private String title;
@Column(name="BriefDetail")
private String briefDetail;
@Column(name="Detail")
private String detail;

public BlogDetails() {
}

public BlogDetails(String EmailId, String Title, String BriefDetail, String      

Detail) {
this.emailId=EmailId;
this.title=Title;
this.briefDetail=BriefDetail;
this.detail=Detail;
}

public int getB_Id() {
return b_Id;
}

public String getEmailId() {
return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getBriefDetail() {
return briefDetail;
}

public void setBriefDetail(String briefDetail) {
this.briefDetail = briefDetail;
}

public String getDetail() {
return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
this.detail = detail;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your table has userid as PRIMARY KEY you cannot use DEFAULT 0 as a value. PRIMARY KEY must be unique and it wont be if you have a default value on it. Change DEFAULT 0 to AUTO_INCREMENT instead.

It never uses the auto incremented value because you never say which column should be auto_increment.